# Can an unmarried niddah go into a cemetery?

Tags: halacha, niddah

The Pitchei Teshuva YD 195:19 cites the Chamudei Daniel as saying that a niddah shouldn't go to a cemetery to daven. The Mishna Brurah 88:7 writes that a niddah shouldn't go to a cemetery. Shiurei Shevet Halevi 195 writes that a niddah shouldn't go to the cemetery because of a concern of mystical reason of tumah. However, it is permitted for her to go and stand 4 amot from the grave.

Does this all apply to a single girl?

Comment: ותישמר שלא תלך לבית הקברות כלל וכלל. (נ"א: ששם מתדבקין הקליפות מאד וכל שכן בנשים), וכל הצרות והעוונות באים מזה Igeres hagra

Comment: Ty, source pls.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Iggeret_HaGra.9?with=all&lang=bi

Answer (score 3):

A woman, married or single, may go as long as its not during actual flow. It's during the actual flow that your sources say a woman should not visit a cemetery (though there are those who argue- see Nitei Gavriel inside). This is from the Nitei Gavriel Aveilus 2:84 .

With regards to yartzeit,and hakamos matzeivah even those who are stringent would be lenient in such a case .

Text of Nitei Gavriel:

[image]

[image]

Comment: The Mishna Brura (88:7, from the OP) says explicitly "until they immerse [in a mikva]".

Comment: I have added a source which brings many sources ,its a machlokes . There is def a strong svarah to say that it is only talking in case when there is an actual flow ,ayin sham